# Как изменить цвет текста в QPushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Столкнулся с проблемой цвет текста сливается с задним фоном, как его (цвет текста в QPushButton) изменить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from ui_inst import Ui_Inst                                    # +++


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '1-int.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Start(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_Start):
        Ui_Start.setObjectName("Ui_Start")
        Ui_Start.resize(443, 293)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 321, 51))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 421, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 210, 141, 58))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 140, 321, 58))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Ui_Start)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ui_Start)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ui_Start):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Ui_Start.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ui_Start", "Ui_Start"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Ui_Start", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Введите номер и букву класса:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "инструкция"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "Найти класс"))



class MyInst(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Inst):                          # +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyInst, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Start):                           #  +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.inst = MyInst()
        self.inst.show()



StyleSheet = '''
QPushButton {
    font: bold italic 16pt 'Comic Sans MS';
    background-color: silver;
    width: 75px ;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background: #C9C0BB; 
}            
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: blue;
}

'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                          # +++

#    Start = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#    ui = Ui_Start()
#    ui.setupUi(Start)
#    Start.show()

    w = Main()
    w.show()
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: если делаете в дизайнере, то там stylesheet с палеткой есть

Comment: Опубликовал, надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Опубликовал код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам `dark.qss`, попробуйте с ним.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from inst import Ui_Inst                                    

class Ui_Start(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_Start):
        Ui_Start.setObjectName("Ui_Start")
        Ui_Start.resize(443, 293)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 321, 51))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Ui_Start)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 421, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 210, 141, 58))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Molot\";")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 140, 321, 58))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Ui_Start)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ui_Start)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ui_Start):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Ui_Start.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ui_Start", "Ui_Start"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Ui_Start", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Введите номер и букву класса:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "инструкция"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "Найти класс"))



class MyInst(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Inst):                          
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyInst, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Start):                           
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.inst = MyInst()
        self.inst.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    # setup stylesheet
    file = QtCore.QFile("dark.qss")                               # !!! dark.qss
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
    stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**dark.qss**

```
QToolTip
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #eff0f1;
    background-color: #31363b;
    alternate-background-color: #3b4045;
    color: #eff0f1;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    opacity: 200;
}

QWidget
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    background-color: #31363b;
    selection-background-color:#3daee9;
    selection-color: #eff0f1;
    background-clip: border;
    border-image: none;
    border: 0px transparent black;
    outline: 0;
}

QWidget:item:hover
{
    background-color: #3daee9;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QWidget:item:selected
{
    background-color: #3daee9;
}

QCheckBox
{
    spacing: 0.5ex;
    outline: none;
    color: #eff0f1;
    margin-bottom: 0.2ex;
    opacity: 200;
}

QCheckBox:disabled
{
    color: #76797c;
}

QGroupBox::indicator
{
    margin-left: 0.2ex;
}

QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked,
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:focus
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_unchecked_disabled.svg);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:hover,
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:pressed,
QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked:hover,
QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked:focus,
QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked:pressed
{
    border: none;
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_unchecked.svg);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_checked.svg);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked:hover,
QCheckBox::indicator:checked:focus,
QCheckBox::indicator:checked:pressed,
QGroupBox::indicator:checked:hover,
QGroupBox::indicator:checked:focus,
QGroupBox::indicator:checked:pressed
{
    border: none;
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_checked.svg);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_indeterminate.svg);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate:focus,
QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate:hover,
QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate:pressed
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_indeterminate.svg);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate:disabled
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_indeterminate_disabled.svg);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked:disabled,
QGroupBox::indicator:checked:disabled
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_checked_disabled.svg);
}

QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:disabled,
QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked:disabled
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_unchecked_disabled.svg);
}

QRadioButton
{
    spacing: 0.5ex;
    outline: none;
    color: #eff0f1;
    margin-bottom: 0.2ex;
}

QRadioButton:disabled
{
    color: #76797c;
}

QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked,
QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:focus
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_unchecked_disabled.svg);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:hover,
QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:pressed
{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_unchecked.svg);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked
{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_checked.svg);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked:hover,
QRadioButton::indicator:checked:focus,
QRadioButton::indicator:checked:pressed
{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_checked.svg);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked:disabled
{
    outline: none;
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_checked_disabled.svg);
}

QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked:disabled
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_unchecked_disabled.svg);
}

QMenuBar
{
    background-color: #31363b;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QMenuBar::item
{
    background: transparent;
}

QMenuBar::item:selected
{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    background-color: #3daee9;
    color: #eff0f1;
    margin-bottom: -0.1ex;
    padding-bottom: 0.1ex;
}

QMenu
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    color: #eff0f1;
    margin: 0.2ex;
}

QMenu::icon
{
    margin: 0.5ex;
}

QMenu::item
{
    padding: 0.5ex 3ex 0.5ex 3ex;
    margin-left: 0.5ex;
    border: 0.1ex solid transparent; /* reserve space for selection border */
}

QMenu::item:selected
{
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QMenu::separator
{
    height: 0.2ex;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-left: 1ex;
    margin-right: 0.5ex;
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:unchecked
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_unchecked_disabled.svg);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:unchecked:selected
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_unchecked_disabled.svg);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:checked
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_checked.svg);
}

QMenu::indicator:non-exclusive:checked:selected
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/checkbox_checked.svg);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:unchecked
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_unchecked_disabled.svg);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:unchecked:selected
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_unchecked_disabled.svg);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:checked
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_checked.svg);
}

QMenu::indicator:exclusive:checked:selected
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/radio_checked.svg);
}

QMenu::right-arrow
{
    margin: 0.5ex;
    border-image: url(:/light/right_arrow.svg);
    width: 0.6ex;
    height: 0.9ex;
}


QWidget:disabled
{
    color: #454545;
    background-color: #31363b;
}

QWidget:focus,
QMenuBar:focus
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #3daee9;
}

QTabWidget:focus,
QCheckBox:focus,
QRadioButton:focus,
QSlider:focus
{
    border: none;
}

QLineEdit
{
    background-color: #232629;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-radius: 0.2ex;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QGroupBox
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-radius: 0.2ex;
    padding-top: 1ex;
    margin-top: 1ex;
}

QGroupBox::title
{
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    subcontrol-position: top center;
    padding-left: 0.1ex;
    padding-right: 0.1ex;
    margin-top: -0.7ex;
}

QTextEdit
{
    background-color: #232629;
    color: #eff0f1;
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
}

QPlainTextEdit
{
    background-color: #232629;;
    color: #eff0f1;
    border-radius: 0.2ex;
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
}

QMainWindow::separator
{
    background-color: #31363b;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 0.4ex;
    spacing: 0.2ex;
    border: 0.1ex dashed #76797c;
}

QMainWindow::separator:hover
{

    background-color: #787876;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 0.4ex;
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    spacing: 0.2ex;
}

QMenu::separator
{
    height: 0.1ex;
    background-color: #76797c;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 0.4ex;
    margin-left: 1ex;
    margin-right: 0.5ex;
}

QFrame[frameShape="2"],  /* QFrame::Panel == 0x0003 */
QFrame[frameShape="3"],  /* QFrame::WinPanel == 0x0003 */
QFrame[frameShape="4"],  /* QFrame::HLine == 0x0004 */
QFrame[frameShape="5"],  /* QFrame::VLine == 0x0005 */
QFrame[frameShape="6"]  /* QFrame::StyledPanel == 0x0006 */
{
    border-width: 0.1ex;
    padding: 0.1ex;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #31363b;
    background-color: #76797c;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}

QToolBar
{
    border: 0.1ex transparent #393838;
    background: 0.1ex solid #31363b;
    font-weight: bold;
}

QToolBar::handle:horizontal
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/hmovetoolbar.svg);
    width = 1.6ex;
    height = 6.4ex;
}

QToolBar::handle:vertical
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/vmovetoolbar.svg);
    width = 5.4ex;
    height = 1ex;
}

QToolBar::separator:horizontal
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/hsepartoolbar.svg);
    width = 0.7ex;
    height = 6.3ex;
}

QToolBar::separator:vertical
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/vsepartoolbars.svg);
    width = 6.3ex;
    height = 0.7ex;
}

QPushButton
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0.5, y1: 0.5 x2: 0.5, y2: 1, stop: 0 #3b4045, stop: 0.5 #31363b);
    border-width: 0.1ex;
    border-color: #76797c;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    border-radius: 0.2ex;
    outline: none;
}

QPushButton:disabled
{
    background-color: #31363b;
    border-width: 0.1ex;
    border-color: #454545;
    border-style: solid;
    padding-top: 0.5ex;
    padding-bottom: 0.5ex;
    padding-left: 1ex;
    padding-right: 1ex;
    border-radius: 0.2ex;
    color: #454545;
}

QPushButton:focus
{
    color: white;
}

QPushButton:pressed
{
    background-color: #31363b;
    padding-top: -1.5ex;
    padding-bottom: -1.7ex;
}

QComboBox
{
    selection-background-color: #3daee9;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-radius: 0.2ex;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    min-width: 7.5ex;
}

QPushButton:checked
{
    background-color: #76797c;
    border-color: #6A6969;
}

QPushButton:hover
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0.5, y1: 0.5 x2: 0.5, y2: 1, stop: 0 #454a4f, stop: 0.5 #3b4045);
    border: 0.1ex solid #3daee9;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QPushButton:checked:hover
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0.5, y1: 0.5 x2: 0.5, y2: 1, stop: 0 #808386, stop: 0.5 #76797c);
    border: 0.1ex solid #3daee9;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QComboBox:hover,
QAbstractSpinBox:hover,
QLineEdit:hover,
QTextEdit:hover,
QPlainTextEdit:hover,
QAbstractView:hover,
QTreeView:hover
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #3daee9;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QComboBox:hover:pressed,
QPushButton:hover:pressed,
QAbstractSpinBox:hover:pressed,
QLineEdit:hover:pressed,
QTextEdit:hover:pressed,
QPlainTextEdit:hover:pressed,
QAbstractView:hover:pressed,
QTreeView:hover:pressed
{
    background-color: #31363b;
}

QComboBox:on
{
    padding-top: 0.3ex;
    padding-left: 0.4ex;
    selection-background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
    background-color: #232629;
    border-radius: 0.2ex;
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    selection-background-color: #3daee9;
}

QComboBox::drop-down
{
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 1.5ex;

    border-left-width: 0ex;
    border-left-color: darkgray;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.3ex;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3ex;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/down_arrow_disabled.svg);
    width: 0.9ex;
    height: 0.6ex;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:on,
QComboBox::down-arrow:hover,
QComboBox::down-arrow:focus
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/down_arrow.svg);
    width: 0.9ex;
    height: 0.6ex;
}

QLabel
{
    border: 0ex solid black;
}

/* BORDERS */
QTabWidget::pane
{
    padding: 0.5ex;
    margin: 0.1ex;
}

QTabWidget::pane:top
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    top: -0.1ex;
}

QTabWidget::pane:bottom
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    bottom: -0.1ex;
}

QTabWidget::pane:left
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    right: -0.1ex;
}

QTabWidget::pane:right
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    left: -0.1ex;
}


QTabBar
{
    qproperty-drawBase: 0;
    left: 0.5ex; /* move to the right by 0.5ex */
    border-radius: 0.3ex;
}

QTabBar:focus
{
    border: 0ex transparent black;
}

QTabBar::close-button
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/close.svg);
    background: transparent;
}

QTabBar::close-button:hover
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/close-hover.svg);
    width: 1.2ex;
    height: 1.2ex;
    background: transparent;
}

QTabBar::close-button:pressed
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/close-pressed.svg);
    width: 1.2ex;
    height: 1.2ex;
    background: transparent;
}


QTabBar::tab:bottom:!selected
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    background-color: #54575B;
    border: 0.1ex transparent black;
    border-left: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2ex;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2ex;
}

QTabBar::tab:bottom:first:!selected
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    background-color: #54575B;
    border: 0.1ex transparent black;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.2ex;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.2ex;
}

QTabBar::tab:bottom:!selected:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    border: 0.1ex rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    border-left: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
}

QTabBar::tab:bottom:!selected:first:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    border: 0.1ex rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
}

/* LEFT TABS */
QTabBar::tab:left
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    border: 0.1ex transparent black;
    border-top: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-right: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    background-color: #31363b;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.2ex;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2ex;
    min-height: 50px;
}

QTabBar::tab:left:last,
QTabBar::tab:left:only-one
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    border: 0.1ex transparent black;
    border-top: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-bottom: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-right: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    background-color: #31363b;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.2ex;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2ex;
    min-height: 50px;
}

QTabBar::tab:left:!selected
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    background-color: #54575B;
    border: 0.1ex transparent black;
    border-top: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.2ex;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2ex;
}

QTabBar::tab:left:!selected:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    border: 0.1ex rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    border-top: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
}

QTabBar::tab:left:!selected:first:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    border: 0.1ex rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
}

/* RIGHT TABS */
QTabBar::tab:right
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    border: 0.1ex transparent black;
    border-top: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-left: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    background-color: #31363b;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.2ex;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2ex;
    min-height: 50px;
}

QTabBar::tab:right:last,
QTabBar::tab:right:only-one
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    border: 0.1ex transparent black;
    border-top: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-bottom: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-left: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    background-color: #31363b;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.2ex;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2ex;
    min-height: 50px;
}

QTabBar::tab:right:!selected
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    background-color: #54575B;
    border: 0.1ex transparent black;
    border-top: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.2ex;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2ex;
}

QTabBar::tab:right:!selected:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    border: 0.1ex rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    border-top: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
}

QTabBar::tab:right:!selected:first:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    border: 0.1ex rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
}

QTabBar QToolButton::right-arrow:enabled
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/right_arrow.svg);
}

QTabBar QToolButton::left-arrow:enabled
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/left_arrow.svg);
}

QTabBar QToolButton::right-arrow:disabled
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/right_arrow_disabled.svg);
}

QTabBar QToolButton::left-arrow:disabled
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/left_arrow_disabled.svg);
}

QTreeView,
QListView
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    background-color: #232629;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/stylesheet-vline.svg) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/stylesheet-branch-more.svg) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/stylesheet-branch-end.svg) 0;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/branch-closed.svg);
}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/branch-open.svg);
}

QTableView::item,
QListView::item,
QTreeView::item
{
    padding: 0.3ex;
}

QTableView::item:!selected:hover,
QListView::item:!selected:hover,
QTreeView::item:!selected:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(61, 173, 232, 0.2);
    outline: 0;
    color: #eff0f1;
    padding: 0.3ex;
}

QSlider::groove:horizontal
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #31363b;
    height: 0.4ex;
    background: #565a5e;
    margin: 0ex;
    border-radius: 0.2ex;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal
{
    background: #232629;
    border: 0.1ex solid #626568;
    width: 1.6ex;
    height: 1.6ex;
    margin: -0.8ex 0;
    border-radius: 0.9ex;
}

QSlider::groove:vertical
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #31363b;
    width: 0.4ex;
    background: #565a5e;
    margin: 0ex;
    border-radius: 0.3ex;
}

QSlider::handle:vertical
{
    background: #232629;
    border: 0.1ex solid #626568;
    width: 1.6ex;
    height: 1.6ex;
    margin: 0 -0.8ex;
    border-radius: 0.9ex;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover,
QSlider::handle:horizontal:focus,
QSlider::handle:vertical:hover,
QSlider::handle:vertical:focus
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #3daee9;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal,
QSlider::add-page:vertical
{
    background: #3daee9;
    border-radius: 0.3ex;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal,
QSlider::sub-page:vertical
{
    background: #626568;
    border-radius: 0.3ex;
}

QPushButton::menu-indicator
{
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: bottom right;
    left: 0.8ex;
}

QTableView
{
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
    gridline-color: #31363b;
    background-color: #232629;
}


QTableView,
QHeaderView
{
    border-radius: 0px;
}

QTableView::item:pressed,
QListView::item:pressed,
QTreeView::item:pressed
{
    background: #3daee9;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QTableView::item:selected:active,
QTreeView::item:selected:active,
QListView::item:selected:active
{
    background: #3daee9;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QListView::item:selected:hover,
QTreeView::item:selected:hover
{
    background-color: #47b8f3;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QTableCornerButton::section
{
    background-color: #31363b;
    border: 0.1ex transparent #76797c;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

QToolBox
{
    padding: 0.5ex;
    border: 0.1ex transparent black;
}

QToolBox:selected
{
    background-color: #31363b;
    border-color: #3daee9;
}

QToolBox:hover
{
    border-color: #3daee9;
}

QStatusBar::item
{
    border: 0px transparent dark;
}

QFrame[height="3"],
QFrame[width="3"]
{
    background-color: #76797c;
}

QSplitter::handle
{
    border: 0.1ex dashed #76797c;
}

QSplitter::handle:hover
{
    background-color: #787876;
    border: 0.1ex solid #76797c;
}

QSplitter::handle:horizontal
{
    width: 0.1ex;
}

QSplitter::handle:vertical
{
    height: 0.1ex;
}


QSpinBox,
QDoubleSpinBox
{
    padding-right: 1.5ex;
}

QSpinBox::up-button,
QDoubleSpinBox::up-button
{
    subcontrol-origin: content;
    subcontrol-position: right top;

    width: 1.6ex;
    border-width: 0.1ex;
}

QSpinBox::up-arrow,
QDoubleSpinBox::up-arrow
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/up_arrow.svg);
    width: 0.9ex;
    height: 0.6ex;
}

QSpinBox::up-arrow:hover,
QSpinBox::up-arrow:pressed,
QDoubleSpinBox::up-arrow:hover,
QDoubleSpinBox::up-arrow:pressed
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/up_arrow-hover.svg);
    width: 0.9ex;
    height: 0.6ex;
}

QSpinBox::up-arrow:disabled,
QSpinBox::up-arrow:off,
QDoubleSpinBox::up-arrow:disabled,
QDoubleSpinBox::up-arrow:off
{
   border-image: url(:/dark/up_arrow_disabled.svg);
}

QSpinBox::down-button,
QDoubleSpinBox::down-button
{
    subcontrol-origin: content;
    subcontrol-position: right bottom;

    width: 1.6ex;
    border-width: 0.1ex;
}

QSpinBox::down-arrow,
QDoubleSpinBox::down-arrow
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/down_arrow.svg);
    width: 0.9ex;
    height: 0.6ex;
}

QSpinBox::down-arrow:hover,
QSpinBox::down-arrow:pressed,
QDoubleSpinBox::down-arrow:hover,
QDoubleSpinBox::down-arrow:pressed
{
    border-image: url(:/dark/down_arrow-hover.svg);
    width: 0.9ex;
    height: 0.6ex;
}

QSpinBox::down-arrow:disabled,
QSpinBox::down-arrow:off,
QDoubleSpinBox::down-arrow:disabled,
QDoubleSpinBox::down-arrow:off
{
   border-image: url(:/dark/down_arrow_disabled.svg);
}
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @5478512 если мои ответы решают вашу проблему, не забывайте отмечать их как правильные и полезные.

Comment: Что в этом случаи делать?  QIODevice::read (QFile, "dark.qss"): device not open

Answer (score 2):

```
button.setStyleSheet('color:red')
```

Comment: `button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{color: red;}")`